# C++ variable declaration and initialization rules

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

Consider the following ways of declaring and initializing a variable of type `C`:

```
C c1;

C c2;
c2 = C();

C c3(C());

C c4 = C();
```

Are all of these completely equivalent to each other, or can some of these differ depending on the exact definition of `C`? (assuming it has public default and copy constructors).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These mean:

```
C c1;   // default constructor

C c2;   // default constructor
c2 = C(); // default constructor followed by assignment

C c3(C());   // default constructor possibly followed by copy constructor

C c4 = C();  // default constructor possibly followed by copy constructor
```

Note the compiler can elide copy constructor calls. Are they equivalent? - well, it depends on what the copy constructor and assignment operator do.

Comment: Note that it is important that even if the copy is elided, the requirements are checked. That is, if the copy constructor is not accessible (private/protected) at this level, 3 and 4 will fail to compile even if the copy constructor is never called.

Comment: @David True, but in this case the question explicitly states that the copy constructor is public.

Comment: So if the copy constructor were private, `c3` and `c4` wouldn't compile, but `c2` still would, right? (including the assignment). What about a call to `func(c2)` - would this also fail to compile with a private copy constructor?

Comment: In case of C3 some compilers (at least Visual Studio) cannot differentiate `C c3(C());` from function declaration. You may need add extra brackets to avoid compiler warning: `C c3((C()));`

Comment: @rom Yes, it would, as would returning a C value.